# Can one write to a wrapped Stream in java?

Tags: java, stream

I'm writing a java server for an assignment, and I have observed some strange behaviour when I write both into a wrapped stream and a wrapper stream, can this cause any problems ? As far as I see, it can, but how ? Pls enlighten me.

as an example:

```
OutputStream os = new OutputStream(...);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
```

And I want to write both in the PrintWriter, and the OutputStream.

Comment: Do you mean you're using both the `PrintWriter` and the `OutputStream` directly to write?

Comment: Exactly, is that a bad idea  ?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer from byte-based stream to character-based stream, you need to use [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html):

> An OutputStreamWriter is a bridge from character streams to byte streams.

So that would be:

```
OutputStream os = ...
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);
```

I think the problem is that you need to specify the encoding, since the constructor `PrintWriter(OutputStream out)` uses the default encoding which might not be correct for your data input:

```
OutputStream os = ...
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, "UTF-8");
```